# Finding devices on network with Bonjour / Zeroconf / jmDNS on PlayBook / Blackberry

Tags: bonjour, blackberry-playbook, zeroconf, jmdns

I would like to develop an Android app which would run on 
Blackberry PlayBook. App would need to find other 
devices on the local network running the same app.

I was thinking to implement Bonjour / Zeroconf / jmDNS 
protocol for finding devices but ...

i just learned that android permission

**android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE**

is not supported on Blackberry or PlayBook. (Preference is 
needed for jmDND (Bonjour) protocol to work.)

https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/

Can you give me some suggestions what would be the best way 
to achieve this on PlayBook. Are there any alternatives?

Is Bonjour possible if building with native SDK or Adobe AIR?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no native support for Bonjour / Zeroconf on PlayBook yet, [check this thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Is-there-a-library-for-Bonjour-mdns-connectivity/m-p/1740173#M4441)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [mDNS Service Discovery](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/29042893/) at Blackberry world.

Here is copy of description:

> mDNS Service Discovery is based on the Avahi open source project. It is a system which facilitates service discovery on a local network via the mDNS/DNS-SD protocol suite. This enables you to plug your laptop or computer into a network and instantly be able to view other people who you can chat with, find printers to print to or find files being shared. Compatible technology is found in Apple MacOS X (branded  Bonjour and sometimes Zeroconf).
>
> The source code is available on the BlackBerry GitHub portal.
>
> mDNS Service Discovery is a part of PlayCloud application - used to find printers.